# Get the image source from a react native <Image> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

Is there a way for me to retrieve the image source uri "profileImage" from the image component and pass it to the function, profileImageFilter(), as 'image source'.

I want 'image source' to be the "uri: profileImage" value

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={profileImageFilter('image source')}>
     <Image style={styles.profileimage} source={{uri: profileImage}}></Image>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You have access to profile image in the render function then why don't you just past it to the function?

See example:

```js
<View>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => profileImageFilter({uri: profileImage})}>
     <Image style={styles.profileimage} source={{uri: profileImage}}></Image>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => profileImageFilter({uri: profileImage2})}>
     <Image style={styles.profileimage} source={{uri: profileImage2}}></Image>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => profileImageFilter({uri: profileImage3})}>
     <Image style={styles.profileimage} source={{uri: profileImage3}}></Image>
</TouchableOpacity>

</View>
```

Comment: Because there will be many images and I want to access this image's specific uri. For simplicity in the question there is one but I am trying to determine which one was clicked and pass its uri string onward

Comment: @MattLaszcz See above it shouldn't matter how many Images there are... Just wrap each in it's own touchable and on press send that uri to the function. See edited code above.

Comment: @MattLaszcz also, note I add () => to your onPress.  You were calling the function onRender rather than waiting for the onPress event to fire in your example.

Comment: oh ok! I was wondering if that's how it worked. So just by passing the URI it already knows it is that specific one for the image since its wrapped in the TouchableOpacity. Thanks!